# Xamarin ClientSocket Crash Application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Im using Client/Server Application 
Server Hosted on Windows
and Client On Android
But When This Script starts:
    TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient();
My Application Crashs

Comment: Do you see an exception or any other error message? The error might be in the output window in VS.

Comment: Did you requested Internet-permission by adding it to the AndroidManifest.xml? https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest/

Comment: @StefanWanitzek What Is The Premssion full name?

Answer (score 0):

You need the INTERNET permission to create sockets in your app.

Add this line to the AndroidManifest.xml (directly under the *manifest*-Tag):

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`